# How do I pass backslashes in a string to a jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

How do I pass backslashes in a string to a jquery ajax call?

In my example **fileFolder** is equal to  **\\server\media\**

```
function getFileList() {

       var fileFolder = $("#fileFolder").val(); //  val equal to \\server\media\

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "service/getFileList",
            data: "{ 'folder': '" + fileFolder + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                ...do stuff here
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe data should be a string, like this:

```
"folder=" + encodeURIComponent(fileFolder) + "&foo=bar"
```

or an object, like this:

```
{folder: fileFolder}
```

jQuery will do the escaping before posting the data. Using the second approach, your code becomes:

```
function getFileList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "service/getFileList",
        data: {
            folder: fileFolder
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            // do stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? what do you see instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change each slash to a double-slash:

```
fileFolder = fileFolder.replace("\","\\");
```

Comment: if i pass '\\test\\test' it works, but if i pass through '\\\\test\\test' it fails - nothing happens.

Comment: test your suggestion before posting

Comment: There are two reasons why this is wrong. 1. The backslashes are still removed when ajaxing. 2. You forgot to escape the replace. fileFolder.replace("\\","\\\\");